# High memory usage with WebClient DownloadData

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have an issue memory not being released after webclient has downloaded data so I tested with the below sample code and it also happens with it. GC collects up to 10-20% of it but that still leaves way too much, I really have no idea what could be wrong as it appears nobody else is having problems with it.

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
    }

    private List<string> list = new List<string>();
    public void DownloadThumb(string Url)
    {
        WebClient ThumbClient = new WebClient();
        ThumbClient.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadFinished;
        ThumbClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(Url));
    }

    private int donecount = 0;
    public void DownloadFinished(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image DownloadedImage;
        using (MemoryStream MemoryStreamTemp = new MemoryStream(e.Result))
        {
            DownloadedImage = Image.FromStream(MemoryStreamTemp);
        }
        DownloadedImage.Dispose();
        ((WebClient)sender).Dispose();

        donecount++;
        if (donecount == list.Count)
        {
            donecount = 0;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        foreach (string TempString in list)
        {
            DownloadThumb(TempString);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should test this using a static HttpClient (`GetByteArrayAsync`), build a `List<Task<Image>>` and `await Task.WhenAll([List of Tasks])`. When the awaited method returns, dispose of all the images. You may see a memory increase nonetheless, but it should plummet each time you repeat the download procedure (since there's some memory pressure). You may call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` after all the images have been disposed, but it's not required, it will happen anyway, when IT deems it necessary -- You should test this running the executable, with TaskManager opened.

Comment: @Jimi Alright Jimi, I'm currently looking at a way to fix it first, if it's not possible then I'll have to look at the alternatives. WebClient is just a tiny part but from what I noticed had the biggest impact, I wanna cry when I think of the work that will be needed to change everything. Why static explicitly though?

Comment: Because that's how HttpClient works, especially when you have concurrent downloads. But it should be used as a static object in any case. WebClient is not made for this. -- Refactoring the code for HttpClient (based on what you have here) takes a few minutes.

Comment: @Jimi So, you don't have any suggestions how to fix the webclient? (Do you get the "leak" too?) Yeah this takes a few minutes, the actual project would be a few days, there's progress tracking, multi threading, api stuff... I looked up the httpclient and even adding something as basic as headers takes a bit of work lol.

Comment: You have an unhealthy combination of WebClient objects (not made for concurrent downloads) that use the same event handler. Most of the memory usage is determined by the by arrays you're creating *in the wrong place*. If you remove the creation of images, it's most probably the same thing -- In the context of the code you have posted here, you just need to replace the WebClient objects declaration with `private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`, then replace `DownloadTaskAsync` with [...]

Comment: `byte[] bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(new Uri(Url)); var image = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(bytes); return image;`. In `async Task DownloadImages()` you then have: `var tasks = new List<Task<Image>>(); list.ForEach(s => tasks.Add(DownloadThumb(s))); await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` -- To add a Header, it's just, e.g.,  `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));` or `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");` -- I'd suggest to declare a `static Lazy<HttpClient>` for this kind of things.

Comment: I also suggest to always associate a HttpClientHandler to the HttpClient object; this is usually done in the same declaration procedure. The HttpClientHandler allows further configuration options, which are most often required, as `SslProtocols`, `AllowAutoRedirect`, `AutomaticDecompression` and `CookieContainer`. --  Note that Microsoft strongly *suggests* not to use WebClient for new development, but HttpClient instead.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for you time, I did a test with https://pastebin.com/Cnh99biJ and it's much better, it only has some 140Mb stuck in HttpContent+LimitMemoryStream, do you have any suggestions regarding that or is that just a httpclient cost?

Comment: After the GC decides to take action, you have some cached stuff that is not subject to garbage collection and actually helps your app to be more *reactive*.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, so to forget about it. Now to read up some on httpclient then get to work rewriting most of the code. Thank you for all that extra work :DDD Write something up so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Glad to help :) Post any refactored code and your findings as an answer after.

Comment: @Jimi Unrelated to the problem, but do you have a tip on how could I pass stuff to other functions via httpclient, on webclient it was simple as .DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(Url), Stuff);

Comment: This has no use in HttpClient, no event is raised, hence you don't need to pass anything to the handler. You have a method (named `DownloadThumb()` in your code) where `GetByteArrayAsync()` is awaited: pass any other data to this method, do whatever you need to do with the data either before or after `GetByteArrayAsync()` returns.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, so you are saying I can't attach any data to request itself directly. I will look at doing it differently then. Thanks.

Comment: That object is not used to pass data to the request directly, it's used to pass some User data to the event handler (retrieved through `e.UserState`). Often used to determine which instance of the WebClient object is raising the event (to track the sequence), but whatever else. Now you have no events, you handle the current request directly. As mentioned, you can pass any data to the async method that awaits `GetByteArrayAsync()` -- You should forget about WebClient and how that thing worked.

Comment: @Jimi "used to pass some User data to the event handler" I know, "You should forget about WebClient" eh, not so easy :P It's documented better and has more help pages on google, It will take some time to switch to httpclient but I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be to change to HttpClient as WebClient is not meant to be used like that, and it's also older and basically obsolete.

With the following code memory usage is 60MB at start > 600 after download > 200 after GC > 70 at some later GC about 90s later.

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media1.giphy.com/media/Uwj2CxFJs8ZyM/giphy.gif");
        list.Add("https://media0.giphy.com/media/5Ut5IWqO2kfDU1FG8T/giphy.gif");
    }

    //Becase https://qa.ostack.cn/qa/?qa=619128
    static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    private List<string> list = new List<string>();
    static readonly HttpClient ThumbClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    public async Task<Image> DownloadThumb(string Url)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await ThumbClient.GetByteArrayAsync(new Uri(Url));
        Image DownloadedImage = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(bytes);
        return DownloadedImage;
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        List<Task<Image>> tasks = new List<Task<Image>>();
        list.ForEach(s => tasks.Add(DownloadThumb(s)));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (Task<Image> task in tasks)
        {
            task.Dispose();
        }
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```